# How to export single cell from google sheets into a text file

Tags: text, google-apps-script, google-sheets, export, cell

I have a Google Sheet with a bunch of numbers that get added up and totalled using the SUM feature.

The totals are in cells D2 and E2

I need a Google Apps Script that will export each of those cells individually to their own .txt files (labelled D2Total.txt & E2Total.txt) in my google drive.

I need them to overwrite themselves every time the script is run because I will be having them update constantly (every few minutes) using the triggers in G Suite.

This is probably pretty straight forward but I am lame when it comes to coding.

I tried some random code on the internet that was kind of close but would only export the entire spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1):

## Append a table of data from Spreadsheet to a Google Doc or Ascii Text File

Assuming you have CSV data in a 'A2' like this '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12
13,14,14,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24 with line delimiters '\n' the you can use this code to create a Google Document and append it as a table or simply export it to an ascii text file.

Export to Google Document:

```
function exportToGDoc() {
  var fn=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM/dd/yy:HH:mm") + '_Report';
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet62');//Need Sheet Name
  var rg=sh.getRange(1,1);
  var csv=rg.getValue();
  var vA=Utilities.parseCsv(csv);
  var fldr=DriveApp.getFolderById('Your Folder Id');//Need Folder Id
  var dk=DocumentApp.create(fn);
  var bd=dk.getBody();
  bd.appendTable(vA)
  dk.saveAndClose();
  var fileId=dk.getId();
  Drive.Files.update({"parents": [{"id": fldr.getId()}]}, dk.getId());//Need to install Drive API
}
```

Export to Ascii Text File:

```
function exportToAsciiText() {
  var fn=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM/dd/yy:HH:mm") + '_Report.csv';
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet62');//Need Sheet Name
  var rg=sh.getRange(1,1);//A1
  var csv=rg.getValue();
  var fldr=DriveApp.getFolderById('Your Folder Id');//Need Folder Id
  var file=fldr.createFile(fn, csv, MimeType.PLAIN_TEXT);
}
```

## Reloading the same ascii text file

```
function exportToAsciiText() {
  var fn='MyReport.csv';//Your report name
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet62');//Need Sheet Name
  var rg=sh.getRange(1,1);//A1
  var csv=rg.getValue();
  var fldr=DriveApp.getFolderById('Your Folder Id');//Need Folder Id
  var files=fldr.getFilesByName(fn);
  var n=0;
  while(files.hasNext()) {
    var file=files.next();
    n++;
  }
  switch (n) {
    case 0:
      var file=fldr.createFile(fn, csv, MimeType.PLAIN_TEXT);
      break;
    case 1:
      file.setContent(csv);
      break;
    default:
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(Utilities.formatString('You have more than one file named %s in folder named %s.',fn,fldr.getName())), 'Error: To many files with that name.');
      break;                                       
  }
}
```

- [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/update)
- [DocumentApp Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document-app)
- [SpreadsheetApp Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app)

Comment: Thank you for your help! That code looks pretty close to what I need for the ASCII Text file... However I just need it to extract one single cell to a txt file that will overwrite itself each time the script is ran.... Also, I found what I thought was my folder ID https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1ZFAKhQ2xqQq5qR0NIM4SrFCmDjCRFQ6i8 
and replaced the GDocsFolderID but it was erroring out?
Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Show me your code and tell me exactly what the error says. You can add it to your question.  When you type the code, select it and press control-K and that will put it into the code panel.

Comment: @fattrain You might just want to try the new code.  In the old function I was using getGlobal('GDocFolderId') and that's a function I use locally.  I forgot to remove it for SO.  All the functions have been updated now

Comment: Worked like a champ! THANK YOU SO MUCH! - The updated code worked fine and I just changed the filename to sample.txt. You're awesome.

Comment: One last hiccup. Sometimes, it will spit the SUM out as way too many digits. For example, right now the SUM of numbers is exactly $3,619.32 but the export actually puts 3619.3199999999997. I double checked that numbers are exact in sheets and not rounding as a "text formatting issue" (especially since I'm only adding up numbers like 34.xx) - Any idea why it would be doing this? Also possible to add comma's? (Like copy the number formatting I have?) - Thanks again!

Comment: Take looked the Number.toFixed() method in JavaScript